# How to read a ListView (restricted Visibility to me) with APEX MetadataService.cls?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, list-view

During my work on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68491/failing-to-get-useful-info-out-of-metadata-api-about-lead-views/68517#68517), I'm trying to retrieve a ListView using this code:

```
public class SFSEMetadataListView {
    public static void readListView() {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort            service         = createService();
        MetadataService.ListView                listView        = (MetadataService.ListView) service.readMetadata(
            'ListView', new String[] { 'Lead.MyListView' }
        ).getRecords()[0];
        System.Debug(JSON.serializePretty(listView));
        if(listView.columns!=null)
            for(String column : listView.columns)
                System.Debug('Column ' + column)
        ;
        if(listView.filters!=null)
            for(MetadataService.ListViewFilter filter : listView.filters)
                System.Debug('Filter ' + filter.field + ' ' + filter.operation + ' ' + filter.value)
        ;
    }
    public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService() {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort            service         = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
            service.SessionHeader               = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
            service.SessionHeader.sessionId     = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        return service;
    }
}
```

**1) Restricted Visibility**

Why ListViews saved "Visible only to me" don't get retrieved and those saved "Visible for all users" actually do get retrieved? How to get "Restricted" ListViews, too?

[image]

**2) Duplicate result properties**

Now in case of "Visible for all users" there is a usable result, however the output of `System.Debug(JSON.serializePretty(listView))` is puzzling:

```
17:38:29.538 (538524558)|USER_DEBUG|[221]|WARN|{
   "fullName" : null,
   "field_order_type_info" : [ "fullName" ],
   "type_att_info" : [ "xsi:type" ],
   "type" : "ListView",
   "sharedTo" : null,
   "queue" : null,
   "language" : null,
   "label" : "MyListView",
   "fullName" : "Lead.MyListView",
   "filterScope" : "Everything",
   "filters" : [ {
      "value" : "a",
      "operation" : "contains",
      "field_order_type_info" : [ "field", "operation", "value" ],
      "field" : "FULL_NAME",
   } ],
   "field_order_type_info" : [ "fullName", "booleanFilter", "columns", "division", "filterScope", "filters", "label", "language", "queue", "sharedTo" ],
   "division" : null,
   "columns" : [ "FULL_NAME", "LEAD.COMPANY", "LEAD.STATE", "LEAD.EMAIL", "LEAD.STATUS", "LEAD.CREATED_DATE", "CORE.USERS.ALIAS", "LEAD.UNREAD" ],
   "booleanFilter" : null,
}
```

The member `fullName` and `field_order_type_info` seem to appear twice and I can't explain how this is possible. However `listView.fullName` outputs 'Lead.MyListView' as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is not possible to retrieve personal list views by any means AFAIK. They do not seem to be saved to the `ListView` object you access via `Metadata API`. This holds true if you are accessing `ListViews` through `ApexPages.StandardSetController` as well. Even when a `User` creates such personal views, they cannot access their own programatically.
2. If you look at the [Documentation](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) for the `MetadataService.ListView` type, those properties are enumerated only once (more would cause a compile error), so that sounds more like an issue with the serialization engine. Have you tried plain `JSON.serialize`?

Answer (score 2):

**Looks like this is now supported by instantiating the sharedTo property.**

It's also possible to retrieve private listviews if the FullName is known.

- Deploy "Visible to all users" (Includes partner and customer portal users)

  ```
  listview.sharedTo = null
  ```
- Deploy "Visible only to me"

  ```
  listview.sharedTo = new SharedTo(
      role = null,
      roles = null,
      queue = null,
      groups = null,
      managers = null,
      territory = null,
      groupNames = null,
      portalRole = null,
      territories = null,
      allPartnerUsers = null,
      allInternalUsers = null,
      managerSubordinates = null,
      channelProgramGroup = null,
      roleAndSubordinates = null,
      channelProgramGroups = null,
      rolesAndSubordinates = null,
      allCustomerPortalUsers = null,
      territoryAndSubordinates = null,
      portalRoleAndSubordinates = null,
      territoriesAndSubordinates = null,
      roleAndSubordinatesInternal = null
  }
  ```

Comment: Interesting approach. However, even though when you edit the list view it says "Visible only to me", other users can still see that list view... Is there anything specific I need to do in addition to the above?

Comment: @BorisBachovski Oh wow :( no idea